# Find all occurrences of a string in a file

Tags: php, string, file, loops

Please keep in mind the file I am opening can be 10mb to 125mb.  I have researched various ways to open a file and am still not sure as to the best approach if any one is best. Please advise!

I am opening a large file and trying to extract the text between two strings each time the first occurs.  I can find the first string and extract the text to the second string, however, my loop gives me that result 12 times (number of times string occurs in this file.  I can see what I am doing wrong in the loop, basically finding the first occurrence and repeating its output 12 times.   How can I loop through the file and get the text between the 2-12th occurrences?

Also, any tips for proper opening of large files and handling memory limits would be great.

If this is put in an array, do I lose the whitespace? I am using PRE to display it correctly as it is.  Ultimately, I want to parse each string found into smaller elements either in an array or a db.  I don't want to get ahead of myself, so ignore the array comments if necessary.

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

/*
Functions
*/

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){ 
    $string = " ".$string; 
    $ini = strpos($string,$start); 
    if ($ini == 0) return ""; 
    $ini += strlen($start); 
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini; 
    return substr($string,$ini,$len); 
} 

/*
Pre Loop
*/

$string1 = "String 1";
$string2 = "String 2";

$report = file_get_contents('report.rpt','r');

$cbcount = substr_count($report,$string1);

echo $cbcount;

/*
Loop
*/

for ($i=0; $i<$cbcount; $i++){

$output = get_string_between($report, $string1, $string2); 

echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never actually advancing any pointer of any kind, so it has no way of knowing that it already found the first match.

Now, depending on your input, you may be able to just use a regex:

```
preg_match_all("(".preg_quote($string1).".*?".preg_quote($string2).")s",$report,$matches);
```

(Replace the entire loop with this)

Then you can `var_dump($matches[0])` to see your output.

Comment: 0 => string 'found'... (length=5048)  I cannot see if each is unique as the output seems like it is not showing the complete string.  What does the above format mean?  String has been replaced by "found".  Googling '... (length=5048) brings up nothing.  I did get 12 strings in the array though.  This is correct.

Comment: I used print_r($matches); and I got the whole string.  Its all there! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$startfrom = 0;
while (($start = strpos($string1, $report, $startfrom)) !== false) {
    $end = strpos($string2, $report, $start);
    echo "<pre>".substr($report, $start, $end-$start)."</pre>";
    $startfrom = $end + 1;
}
```

Regarding dealing with large files, instead of reading the entire thing into memory, you can use `fopen()` and `fgets()` to read it line by line. When you find a line containing the `$string1` you start accumulating lines in in a variable, until you find the line containing `$string2`. This only works simply if the match strings cannot contain newlines.

Comment: I check this later. The newlines were on my list to check with fgets() and others.  Thanks for the response.